# Gate errors on Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, authorization

I'm following a tutorial about Authorization in laravel, but it seems it got some errors in the code like this:

```
"Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Providers\Post, instance of App\Post given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\cms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 323 ◀"
```

I got those error code when I'm accessing http://cms.dev/posts/edit/2. here's the code that i've put on AuthServicesProfider:

```
public function registerPostPolicies()
    {
        Gate::define('create-post', function ($user) {
            return $user->hasAccess(['create-post']);
        });
        Gate::define('update-post', function  ($user, Post $post) {
            return $user->hasAccess(['update-post']) or $user->id == $post->user_id;
        });
        Gate::define('publish-post', function ($user) {
            return $user->hasAccess(['publish-post']);
        });
        Gate::define('see-all-drafts', function ($user) {
            return $user->inRole('editor');
        });
    }
```

and here's the code for the update.blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Update Post</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('update_post', ['post' => $post->id]) }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="title" class="col-md-4 control-label">Title</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{ old('title', $post->title) }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('body') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="body" class="col-md-4 control-label">Body</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" required>{{ old('body', $post->body) }}</textarea>
                                    @if ($errors->has('body'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('body') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Update
                                    </button>
                                    @can('publish-post')
                                        <a href="{{ route('publish_post', ['post' => $post->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            Publish
                                        </a>
                                    @endcan
                                    <a href="{{ route('list_posts') }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Cancel
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

I really have no idea about how to fix it since i really don't understand about authorization in Laravel. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a **use** statement for the **Post** class, therefore PHP assumes the gate takes the **Post** class from the current namespace, hence the **App\Providers\Post** in the error message.

Add the following in the provider class:

```
use App\Post;
```

Comment: i should put that on PostController?

Comment: ah u right, I got no error when I've put it on AuthProvider. Thanks

Comment: I am getting same error when use App\Post; in AuthServiceProvider class. Please help me.